# fedora 24 external HD did not boot anymore

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2

I have a extern HD with a fedora 24 installation. If I try to start from that device I get the grub start screen and can select a list of several kernels, but none of them did start. After pressing the enter key on a selected item I see only a blinking "_" and thats it.

I can mount the /sdc1 partition of that not booting HD and also the llvm partitions I can mount if I start from an other linux disk.

So I can do a full backup and a reinstall, but I believe it can not be so hard to make that device bootable again without a full new installation. Because grub is starting I believe the bootblock is valid. What can I test and change?